# How do you use the Explorer tree is VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find the explorer tree to be unintuitive.  Opening a file on single click was annoying, so I set `"workbench.list.openMode": "doubleClick"`.  Now I have to click twice on the expand/collapse triangle just to make the tree expand or collapse (in code outline view, gitlens, and other views).

Shouldn't single click on the twisty open/close?

Why can't you type letters to navigate in lists/trees?

Why is the item you clicked on one color, but the item you navigate to with arrow keys another?

What is the point of the other highlight, as the context menu only seems to apply to the highlight with less contrast?

How do I open the selected item with the keyboard?

What is happening in the explorer when you press ESC?  Seems like focus moves to the tree itself, but what does that achieve?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't single click on the twisty open/close?

I've seen an open issue about that

> Why can't you type letters to navigate in lists/trees?

That issue exists too

> Why is the item you clicked on one color, but the item you navigate to with arrow keys another?

IDK. Usually, after you click that file is open in editor. (Selected list item - active editor(easier to spot?); Focused list item - where the focus is)

> What is the point of the other highlight, as the context menu only seems to apply to the highlight with less contrast?

You can change the colors if you want to.

> How do I open the selected item with the keyboard?

<kbd>Enter</kbd>? I assigned arrow right<kbd>→</kbd> though.

> What is happening in the explorer when you press ESC? Seems like focus moves to the tree itself, but what does that achieve?

What did you expect it to do?

Comment: The two forms of selection is very strange.  You can multi-select files A and B, then move focus to C, and if you invoke delete, it deletes only file C (the item with focus).  But if you move focus back to B and press delete, now it deletes both A and B.  
A selected list item is not always the active editor.  An item can be selected even if the file is not open, or if it's a folder, or if you have multiple things selected.